# Automatically remove associated records if not present in update params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

We're using Rails 5.2.2.1 as an API with Vue for the frontend.

A `Post` `has_many :tags`.  A `Post` also `accepts_nested_attributes_for :tags, allow_destroy: true`.

When creating a post, you create the tags at the same time and this works well.  When editing tags, however, I'm running into an issue where tags that aren't present in the update payload are not deleted from the database.  Here's an example of what I'd expect:

```
# A Post has currently tags with ID 1, 2, and 3.
# This (pseudo) update payload is sent
{
  tags_attributes: [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Tech'
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'Sports'
    },
    {
      id: nil,
      name: 'Science'
    }
  ]
}

# The post's tag with an ID of 2 is not present in the update payload, so it should be automatically removed
# Since we're also passing up a new tag without an ID, this tag should be created
```

I have a solution involving `_destroy: '1'`, but it would be preferable for tags to be automatically marked for destruction based on their presence in the update payload.

Comment: It might help if you show some relevant code. Where is it you expect the unused `tags` to be deleted? What does that code look like?

Comment: That's the core of what I'm asking.  Currently, there is no server-side code to do this in my application.  It's handled client-side by setting a `_destroy` key on the deleted `tags`.

In the same way Rails will automatically delete associated records if it has a `_destroy` key, I was looking for some advice on how to accomplish the same result, but based on the presence or absence of a `tag` in the update payload

Comment: By default, Rails protects the nested attributes unless the ‘allow_destroy: true’ option is used along with the ‘_destroy’ attribute. Does your use case not work with this convention?